# Django model: TypeError: 'Manager' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I'm developing a Rest API with django. I have this model:

```
from django.db import models
from devices.models import Device

class Command(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    command_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    timeout = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    command_status= models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    tracking = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    result_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
    ssid = models.CharField(max_length=31, blank=False, default='')
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in the views I have this part of code:

```
@csrf_exempt 
def command_detail(request, rssid):
    try: 
    print("Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelllo 1111 rssid: ", rssid)
    commands=Command.objects().filter(ssid=rssid)
    print("Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelllo 2222")
    command=commands[0]
    except Command.DoesNotExist: 
    return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

If I execute my server it works fine without any error but if I trie to test the corresponding server with curl like that: `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/commands/cmdssid1?command_status=40` I get as curl result a so big html indicating an Internal Error in the server and in the django part I got those traces:

```
July 30, 2019 - 08:00:01
Django version 1.10.1, using settings 'project-name.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
('Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelllo 1111 rssid: ', u'cmdssid1')
Internal Server Error: /api/commands/cmdssid1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path-to-home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/path-to-home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/path-to-home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/path-to-home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path-to-project/command/views.py", line 56, in command_detail
    commands=Command.objects().filter(ssid=rssid)
TypeError: 'Manager' object is not callable
[30/Jul/2019 08:00:06] "POST /api/commands/cmdssid1?command_status=40 HTTP/1.1" 500 74917
```

I made many searches and I investigated with some debugs but really not clear what's the main cause to fix the issue.

Has any one an idea what's the cause of the error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this line:

```
commands=Command.objects().filter(ssid=rssid)
```

Use the following line

```
commands=Command.objects.filter(ssid=rssid)
```

Because, as the error said, [**`Manager`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/) object is not callable. You need to use it without the brackets.

Comment: Great thank you very much :) simpler then I thought